# IF ELSE Statement in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, sfmc-business-unit

I have problem with IF/ELSE statement in Ampscript ,as it is not going through else statement

I have created a DE for couponcode Claim
coupon DE details(CouponCodeRedeem)
CouponCode - CouponCode
EmailAddress - Email to which coupon is sent
IsClaimed - is set to Y once emai; with is sent to customer
IsRedeemed - updated based on external system response ; used to send reminder email if coupon is not redeemed.

Receipient DE details
EmailAddress - email address of the recipient
Name - name of recipient

i have populated "coupon code for 3 rows in my DE , where IsRedeemed  is set to Y for 1 coupon code and remaining 2 rows have value has false .

I'm trying to send coupon to customers for which new customers( IsRedeemed ="False") , but it is not going thorugh my else statement and check my if statement and sends the coupon for (Isredeemed = True) for 1 recipient .

[image]

Code Syntax :

```
%%[
var @email,@row,@couponRow, @couponCode,@ClaimedDate,@IsRedeemed,@barcode

set @rows = LookupRows("CouponCodeRedeem","IsRedeemed","Y")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)



if @rowCount > 0 then
output(concat("rowcount: ", @rowcount))
  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @emailAddress, @couponCode
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @emailAddress = field(@row,"EmailAddress")
    set @couponCode = field(@row,"CouponCode")
    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, couponCode: %%=v(@couponCode)=%%, emailAddress: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%/*setting coupon against new customers*/

set @email = AttributeValue("emailAddr")
output(concat("email: ", @email))
set @couponRow = ClaimRow("CouponCodeRedeem", "IsClaimed", "EmailAddress", @email)

if not empty(@couponRow) then

  set @couponCode = Field(@couponRow, "CouponCode")
set @barcode = BarcodeURL(@couponCode, "Code128Auto", 300, 100)
set @ClaimedDate = Field(@couponRow, "ClaimedDate")
else

  RaiseError("No coupons available")

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your lookup statement. combined with the if - statement

```
set @rows = LookupRows("CouponCodeRedeem","IsRedeemed","Y")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then
  //do something
else
```

You only make a count of columns where IsRedeemed == true and then iterate over these results.
Your code will only reach the part of the else, when no results where found.

Comment: Hi Daniel , but i have only one codition to check and split the rows based on IsRedeemed value . Should i need to add AND condition in initial if block like

 if( rowcount > 0 AND IsRedeemed = "Y") .

if( rowcount > 0){
do something 
}
else {
if(@copuon row not empty){ 
do something }
else {
throw error
}
}

Comment: Hi, I think you should do something like this: set @rows = LookupRows("CouponCodeRedeem","IsClaimed","False")     then you can iterate the rows and for each one you can decide what to do dependent to the value of IsRedeemed